# Loop and sum in python with user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I'm trying to calculate the budget by asking the user to enter the amount they want to budget and break it down by specific amount and substract that amount from the original with every iteration
and show them the last result

```
budget = int(input("Please enter the amount you have budgeted for this month: "))

print(budget)

expensess = ['Rent','Food','Car','Gym','Phone','Travel','Savings']


balance=0
budget = budget
for i in expensess:

    added_balance = int(input('How much did you budget for '+str(i)))
    new_balance = int(budget - added_balance)
    print(new_balance)
    balance += new_balance
    budget = balance
    print("budget is "+str(budget))
    

if balance is > budget:
    print("You underbudgeted ")
else:
    print('Good Job you would have extra money to spend'+ )
```

when I run this

```
Python 3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
=== RESTART: C:\Users\boxfo\Desktop\Programming Challenges\Budget Analysis.py ==
Please enter the amount you have bugeted for this month: 6000
6000
How much did you budget for Rent2000
budget is 4000
How much did you budget for Food2000
budget is 6000
How much did you budget for Car3000
budget is 9000
How much did you budget for Gym
```

Comment: Hint: you write `new_balance = int(budget - added_balance)` and also write `balance += new_balance`. Meaning you subtract from budget yet also add that result to the budget.

Comment: Can you elaborate what is the issue which you are facing in the above code?

Comment: My Code was supposed to calculate the Amount of money left after substracting expenses from the main Budget, but my mistake was i was substracting from the main budget not the new budget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should decrease the budget variable and you can calculate everything what you want in your question:

```
budget -= balance
```

I have written a working version from your code with some comments.

**Code:**

```
budget = int(input("Please enter the amount you have budgeted for this month: "))

expensess = ["Rent", "Food", "Car"]

for i in expensess:
    added_balance = int(input("How much did you budget for {}: ".format(i)))
    budget -= added_balance  # decrease the budget variable with the spend money
    print("Current budget is {}".format(budget))

if 0 > budget:  # If the budget is a minus number then you are underbudgeted.
    print("You underbudgeted: {}".format(abs(budget)))  # Creating ABS from negative number and print the difference.
else:
    print("Good Job you would have extra money to spend: {}".format(budget))
```

**Tests:**

Underbudgeted:

```
>>> python3 test.py
Please enter the amount you have budgeted for this month: 6000
How much did you budget for Rent: 2000
Current budget is 4000
How much did you budget for Food: 2000
Current budget is 2000
How much did you budget for Car: 3000
Current budget is -1000
You underbudgeted: 1000
```

Good job:

```
>>> python3 test.py
Please enter the amount you have budgeted for this month: 6000
How much did you budget for Rent: 2000
Current budget is 4000
How much did you budget for Food: 1000
Current budget is 3000
How much did you budget for Car: 1000
Current budget is 2000
Good Job you would have extra money to spend: 2000
```

Comment: If my answer answered your question, please mark it as "answered". Others SO users should see that your questions has already been answered! :)

Answer (score 0):

I've changed a bit your code. Just have a look:

```
budget = int(input("Please enter the amount you have budgeted for this month: "))
```

print("Total budget %d " % (budget) + "\n")

expenses_list = ["Rent", "Food", "Car", "Gym", "Phone", "Travel", "Savings"]

expenses = 0

for i in expenses_list:

```
added_balance = int(input("How much did you budget for " + str(i) + "\t"))

# CHECK IF THE ADDED BUDGET IS GREATER THAN THE TOTAL BUDGET (budget)
if added_balance > budget:
    print("Your expense cannot be higher than your total budget!")
    exit()  # TERMINATES THE PROGRAMM OR ASK ANOTHER VALUE IF YOU WANT

expenses += added_balance

# NOW CHECK IF YOUR EXPENSES ARE ALREADY OVER THE BUDGET
if (budget - expenses) < 0:
    print(
        "YOUR EXPENSES HAVE REACHED %d" % (expenses)
        + " AND YOUR BUDGET IS %d" % (budget)
    )
    exit()  # TERMINATES THE PROGRAMM OR ASK ANOTHER VALUE IF YOU WANT

print("ADDED BUDGET: %d" % (added_balance))
print(
    "CURRENT BALANCE IS: %d " % (budget - expenses)
    + "\n ------------------------ \n"
)
```

Comment: And you should also check if the user has informed a valid value, like so:

`budget = input("Please enter the amount you have budgeted for this month: ")`
`if(budget.isnumeric():`
     then do the rest
`else:`
`print('invalid value')`

Comment: Last night i ended up fixing the bug but came to the same conclusion as your code, but mine would return to the first condition when the budget get to 0

Comment: ok, most important is that you've got the idea